# Is this set connected or path connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

How to check the $S =\{(x,y)\mid  x+y \in \mathbb{Q}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R^2}$ under usual topology is connected or path-connected?

My approach is, not path-connected because if we pick any two points within this set as joined by a continuous curve that is clearly not lying within the set, and I have no idea how to prove or disprove connected or not?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question ?

Comment: Isn't a path connected set also connected? Thus if it is not path connected, then it can not be connected.

Comment: @Filippo The implication goes the other way. If a set isn’t connected it can’t be path connected.

Comment: the path connected implies connected but not path-connected set may or may not be connected.

Comment: When you say it’s clear that no two points in the set can be joined by a path, maybe you should think about the fact that the line $x+y=0$ is a subset of $S$, and so the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,-1)$ can be joined by the path $\gamma:[0,1]\to S$ given by $\gamma(t) = (t,-t)$.

Comment: "not path-connected because if we pick any two points within this set as joined by a continuous curve that is clearly not lying within the set" this is saying it's not path connected because it's not path connected. Not very convincing if the reader doesn't already believe it...

Comment: $S$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R\times\mathbb Q$, via $(x,y)\mapsto(x,x+y)$.

Answer (score 2):

The image of a connected space under a continuous map is connected. The map $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $(x,y) \mapsto x+y$ is continuous. However, $f(S) = \mathbb{Q}$ is disconnected.

You argument for the non-path-connectedness is not convincing, and in fact plain wrong. There are plenty of points connected by paths inside $S$, e.g. $(0, 0)$ is connected to $(1, -1)$ via $\gamma(t) = (t, -t)$.